# Passing scope object to Angular Directive via $compile

Tags: angularjs, directive

I know that if I have a directive in HTML, I can pass objects from my $scope to it:

```
<mydirective some-data="someData"></mydirective>
```

...where `someData` might be JSON object.

Is it possible to pass a reference to `someData` if I create the directive dynamically and use `$compile`?

```
$scope.someData = { firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe' };

var link = $compile("<mydirective some-data='???'></mydirective>");
var content = link($scope);
$(body).append(content);
```

Comment: Have you tried ``$compile("<mydirective some-data='someData'></mydirective>");``? (the name of the var you just set in you ``$scope``)

Comment: @jlowcs omg that was so easy, and now, so obvious. Thank you so much.

Comment: @jlowcs you should add this as an answer, it's easier & clearer then to find it

Answer (score -2):

Yes you can pass object to

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.directive('passObject', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: { obj: '=' },
        template: '<div>Hello, {{obj.prop}}!</div>'
    };
});

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.obj = { prop: "world" };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.12/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <pass-object obj="obj"></pass-object>
</div>
```

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.directive('passObject', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: { obj: '=' },
        template: '<div>Hello, {{obj.prop}}!</div>'
    };
});

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.obj = { prop: "world" };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <pass-object obj="obj"></pass-object>
</div>
```

directive